# Can you figure out my name?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

I can be mad, I can be wrong,

Both my lines are equally long,

With out I cancel a mistake,

With up I fake,

I have a green opposite,

And a hollow opponent when you see me in a game,

Can you figure out my name?

Comment: **Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!** Just to confirm, this is your own riddle right?

Comment: Yes it is mine!

Comment: No problem. Don't take this seriously, it's a routine check since many first-comers post homework problems, etc. Have a good time! This puzzle sure looks interesting.

Comment: My bad I thought bedazzle meant to lie let me edit the question.

Comment: "All that's puzzling you is just the nature of my game!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your name is:

> **CROSS**

I can be mad, I can be wrong,

> Cross can mean mad and the cross symbol (x) could signify that something is wrong.

Both my lines are equally long,

> The cross symbol normally is made of two lines of equal size overlapping each other

With out I cancel a mistake,

> Cross out means to cancel

With up I fake,

> Cross up means to deceive someone.

I have a green opposite,

> A green tick as in the checkmark!

And a hollow opponent when you see me in a game,

> A nought ‘O’ in noughts and crosses.

Answer (score 2):

Your name is:

> Red Cross - as "I have a green opposite"

I put it more as comment/amendment to PDT answer (less then 50 reputation)

Comment: Less than 50 reputation isn't a reason to circumvent rules, but posting the solution of your own puzzle is allowed. +1